# Get consensus within each columns of a group in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Groups COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 
G1     A    NaN  I    J
G1     A    NaN  I    J
G1     NaN  NaN  Z    J
G1     B    K    Z    J
G2     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
G2     NaN  NaN  K    NaN
G3     NaN  B    C    D
G3     NaN  C    C    D
G3     NaN  B    C    E
```

---

And I would like for :

1 -  First, for each `Group` and `Column,` to get a consensus column, such as:

```
Groups COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 cc_COL1 cc_COL2 cc_COL3 cc_COL4
G1     A    NaN  I    J    A       K       I       J
G1     A    NaN  I    J    A       K       I       J
G1     NaN  NaN  Z    J    A       K       Z       J
G1     B    K    Z    J    A       K       Z       J
G2     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN     K       NaN
G2     NaN  NaN  K    NaN  NaN     NaN     K       NaN
G3     NaN  B    C    D    NaN     B       C       D
G3     NaN  C    C    D    NaN     B       C       D
G3     NaN  B    C    E    NaN     B       C       D
```

When two value within a `Group` and a `column` are with equal numbers, I take the first one.

---

2-  And in second step to get a `representaitve_column` for each groups :

Where this column takes the `non-NaN` value in that order of the following columns :

```
cc_COL1,cc_COL2,cc_COL3 and cc_COL4
```

So for instance if there is `NaN` in `cc_COL1`, `representative_column` takes the value of `cc_COL2`, but if `cc_COL2` in also `NaN,` it takes the value of `cc_COL3` and so on until `cc_COL4`. If all are `NaN`, then I put `NaN`.

I should then get, in that example, the following output:

```
Groups COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 cc_COL1 cc_COL2 cc_COL3 cc_COL4 representative_column
G1     A    NaN  I    J    A       K       I       J       A
G1     A    NaN  I    J    A       K       I       J       A
G1     NaN  NaN  Z    J    A       K       Z       J       A
G1     B    K    Z    J    A       K       Z       J       A
G2     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN     K       NaN     K
G2     NaN  NaN  K    NaN  NaN     NaN     K       NaN     K
G3     NaN  B    C    D    NaN     B       C       D       B
G3     NaN  C    C    D    NaN     B       C       D       B
G3     NaN  B    C    E    NaN     B       C       D       B
```

Here is the dataframe in dict format if it can helps :

```
{'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G2', 5: 'G2'}, 'COL1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: nan, 3: 'B', 4: nan, 5: nan}, 'COL2': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 'K', 4: nan, 5: nan}, 'COL3': {0: 'I', 1: 'I', 2: 'Z', 3: 'Z', 4: nan, 5: 'K'}, 'COL4 ': {0: 'J', 1: 'J', 2: 'J', 3: 'J', 4: nan, 5: nan}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tmp_df = df.apply(lambda col: col.groupby(df['Groups']).transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0] if len(x.mode())>0 else np.nan)).drop('Groups', axis=1)
df['representative_column'] = tmp_df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Groups COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 cc_COL1 cc_COL2 cc_COL3 cc_COL4 representative_column
0     G1    A  NaN    I    J       A       K       I       J                     A
1     G1    A  NaN    I    J       A       K       I       J                     A
2     G1  NaN  NaN    Z    J       A       K       I       J                     A
3     G1    B    K    Z    J       A       K       I       J                     A
4     G2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN       K     NaN                     K
5     G2  NaN  NaN    K  NaN     NaN     NaN       K     NaN                     K
6     G3  NaN    B    C    D     NaN       B       C       D                     B
7     G3  NaN    C    C    D     NaN       B       C       D                     B
8     G3  NaN    B    C    E     NaN       B       C       D                     B
```